# construct and apply affine transformation matrix

Tags: matlab, affinetransform

I am trying to construct affine transformation matrix through a parameter vactror of rotation angle, scaling, shearing and displacement values all in a vector named phai.
The vector is organized as follow:

```
phai=[rotationAngle, scalingCoefX, scalingCoefY, shearingCoefX, shearingCoefY, translationCoefX, translationCoefY]';
```

To construct the affine transformation matrix I apply the following code:

```
rotation=[cos(phai(1)) sin(phai(1)) 0; -sin(phai(1))cos(phai(1)) 0; 0 0 1];
scaling=[phai(2) 0 0; 0 phai(3) 0; 0 0 1];
shearingY=[1 0 0; phai(5) 1 0; 0 0 1];
shearingX=[1 phai(4) 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1];
translation=[1 0 0; 0 1 0; phai(6) phai(7) 1];
T=rotation*scaling*shearingY*shearingX*translation;
T = maketform('affine',T);
```

Then to apply the result to an image (c) I perform:

```
c=imtransform(c,T);
```

Due to the implementation requirements, I have to define 200 different compunation of parameter values. Therefore phai in general is a 200x7 matrix where each row contains 7 values of different affine parameters' values.

For the execution time, it is: 48.375s for the Total Time of the 200 phai and 0.452s for Self Time.

My questions are: is this code represent a right implementation of the affine transformation? does the execution time is acceptable? is there any suggestions to speed up the execution in the case that the code is right?

Thank you very much

Comment: Which part takes a long time? You can time it and identify that. What are the sizes of the matrices? Please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can replicate your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, In general, there are 200 phai therefore the total size of phai is 200x7. For the execution time, it is: 48.375s for the Total Time of the 200 phai and 0.452s for Self Time. Is this execution time acceptable?

Comment: You should add that to the question. Not to the comments. Please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have a much higher change of getting more and better answers if you actually put in the efforts of creating one. I can't stress this enough.

Comment: Sitll, there is no enough information. The piece of code you posted shouldnt take that long to compute. I am guessing there are more things involved. Please, post the whole code with an image of the profiler!